# What is the rationale for being able to answer questions before commenting on them?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a very regular user, but recently have decided to try my hand at helping others. I am wondering why I can answer questions at a lower reputation level than commenting on them (50 rep required). Good answers require a fair bit of testing, formatting and so on to make sure nobody's time is being wasted. They're not for asking for clarification etc.

But few questions in the tags I've looked at that I could contribute to are sufficiently detailed in their initial data for me to answer. Or sometimes they are questions that are solved easily via a simple google of the right term. So in that case I want to just say (comment) "This is the library you're looking for. Implementation docs are here". I could try warping my answer with psuedo code but that seems unfair to the reviewers/mods and puts my rep at risk.

There seems to be a lot of design and history of design at SO so undoubtedly this was done by intention. Rather than guess though, I was wondering if you can verify the reason comments are a privilege to come after answering, flagging and voting. There doesn't appear to be any history on why this is a privilege on the comment page itself.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but will comment instead (oh the irony).  You should answer questions that you can answer, even if you don't know the answer prior to research with Google or other sites.  Including code is always good, but real code (that you know compiles and/or runs) is much better than pseudo.  You'll be commenting in under a day.

Comment: @codeMagic It's pretty close to the linked question, but differs in that this is asking for rationale.  The other question asks what to do instead.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg read the Meta post that the linked post refers to. It explains *why*. The answer is in that castle

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, the link in the answer covers this in full.  I concur with your duplicate vote.

Answer (score 0):

per CodeMagic's link's link it has been answered previously here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174

I'm not sure if I'm meant to answer my own post when a commenter provided the answer?

Comment: there is a close vote pending, when duplicates are found the question can be vote closed for that reason. Which when passed will close the question and point users to the other.